# Why do I get 'Cannot read property 'isValid' of undefined' when using 400 data points?

Tags: highcharts, timeline

I am trying to visualise more than 400 data points using highcharts timeline, but I'm getting `Cannot read property 'isValid' of undefined`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0fv2kxqb/

```js
const test = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
  test.push({
    x: Date.UTC(1900 + i, 9, 4),
    name: 'test'
  });
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    zoomType: 'x',
    type: 'timeline'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    visible: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    title: null,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Timeline of Space Exploration'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Info source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_space_exploration">www.wikipedia.org</a>'
  },
  tooltip: {
    style: {
      width: 300
    }
  },
  series: [{
    dataLabels: {
      allowOverlap: false,
      format: '<span style="color:{point.color}">● </span><span style="font-weight: bold;" > ' +
        '{point.x:%d %b %Y}</span><br/>{point.label}'
    },
    marker: {
      symbol: 'circle'
    },
    data: test
  }]
});
```

```css
#container {
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/timeline.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

It works fine with ~300 data points

Does it not work with large amounts of data points?

Comment: Post all relevant code here directly as text as an [mcve].

Comment: This bug have been reported on [github](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11116). Look there for more detail and the workaround used too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That problem is a bug and it is reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11116

**Possible workarounds:**

- set `cropThreshold` bigger than data length: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rtkj5xd7/
- enable `getExtremesFromAll`: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rtkj5xd7/2/